# How to make a process with human interaction in jBPM 6?

Tags: jbpm

I'm a newbie to jbpm and started that with **jbpm 6**. I'm assigned a task of designing a process using jBPM. The task details are as follows:
Motive : Customer registration

Step 1: Details of the customer are filled by person A(may be Receptionist).
Step 2: The details are shown to person B(may be Manager).
Step 3: person B approves/disapproves the customer to be registered.
Step 4: if APPROVED : Customer registered; if DISAPPROVED: Details dumped.

Now, I need to know how to built it from scratch and also want to know how to actually design a process which contains human interaction using forms.
PS: Please don't use the predefined samples like all the tutorials on the web, where they just show how to run a ready made sample.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And also, I forgot to mention, after customer registration, an email and SMS has to be sent to the customer. So how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are completely new to the tool you will find useful an already working example, so you can modify it and adapt it to your own needs. Look at this post: 
http://salaboy.com/2013/10/11/using-the-jbpm-console-ng-hr-example/

There are also some other posts in my blog that will help you to get started. 
Notice that those examples covers most or your needs, so I definitely recommend you going over those examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot @salaboy for answering. I went through all the examples you have explained in your blog. I got the concept of how things are working i.e human task,etc. But I'm unable to understand where to write the java code and all other codes and how to design and attach the forms with the human tasks?